# exception while transferring files in socket

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I am working here on a client-server file transfer application through socket. here, my problem is my client is throwing exception saying that the socket is closed while the server side is still on. And its still prompting for the next file name to be sent. I have not closed the socket or anything else here.

here is the code:

Server side:

```
public void soc_server() throws IOException {

    servsock = new ServerSocket(55000);

    sock = servsock.accept();
    pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
    System.out.println("Hello Server");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("how many files to be sent: ");
    String temp = sc.nextLine();
    temp = temp.trim();
    int fileNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    // sc.close();
    // sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int x = 0; x < fileNumber; x++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name or file path ");

        String s = sc.nextLine();

        File file = new File(s);

        if (file.exists())
            System.out.println("File found");
        else
            System.out.println("File not found");

        out = sock.getOutputStream();

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(s);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];

        int bytesRead = 0;

        System.out.println("sending file no: " + x);

        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            if (bytesRead > 0) {

                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                totalSent += bytesRead;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("sent " + (totalSent / 1024) + " KB "
                + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000) + " sec");

        out.flush();

        pw.print(s);

        pw.flush();
    }

    fileInputStream.close();

    out.close();

    pw.close();

    System.out.println("Sent " + (totalSent / 1024) + " kilobytes in "

    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000) + " seconds");

    sock.close();

    servsock.close();

    sc.close();

}
```

client side code:

```
public void soc_client() throws Exception {
    sock = new Socket("172.16.27.106", 55000);
    System.out.println("Hello Client");

    while (sock.isConnected() == true) {

        in = sock.getInputStream();

        File outputFile = new File("outputFile");

        if (outputFile.exists())
            System.out.println("File found");
        else {
            System.out.println("File not found");

            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];

        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            totalRecieved += bytesRead;

        }
        System.out
                .println("Recieved " + (totalRecieved / 1024)
                        + " kilobytes in "
                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000)
                        + " seconds");

        fileOutputStream.flush();

        fileOutputStream.close();

        in = sock.getInputStream();

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String fileName = br.readLine();

        fileName = fileName + "";

        System.out.println(fileName);

        File file = new File(fileName);

        file.createNewFile();

        boolean success = outputFile.renameTo(file);

        if (!success) {

            System.out.println(" file renaming is unsuccessful ");
        } else {

            outputFile.delete();
        }

        in.close();

        br.close();

    }
    if (sock.isConnected() == true) {
        System.out.println(" connection stays ");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" connection terminated ");
    }

    System.out
            .println("Recieved "
                    + (totalRecieved
                            / (1024 * 1024)
                            + " MB in "
                            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / (1000 * 60)) + " minutes"));
}
```

the exception on client side:

```
Press 1 to be server
Press 2 to be client
Press 3 to be emergency exit
2
Hello Client
File not found
Recieved 42 kilobytes in 12.148 secondsException in thread "main" 
null
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at Client.soc_client(Client.java:28)
at Index.main(Index.java:25)
```

Server side prompting:

```
asus@CM1855:~/Desktop$ java Index
Press 1 to be server
Press 2 to be client
Press 3 to be emergency exit
1
Hello Server
how many files to be sent: 
2
Please enter the file name or file path 
Bill of cloud draft.docx
File found
sending file no: 0
sent 36 KB 20 sec
Please enter the file name or file path
```

Comment: I doubt you can call `getInputStream` on the same socket multiple times, the way you do.

Comment: @Heuster I suggest you try it, instead of just posting your guesswork here.

Comment: @EJP Haha thanks for your tip. Next time I'll think twice. It's good that there are people like you who keep this site perfect. I wish I could be a little more like you.

Comment: @Heuster Being 'more like me' has nothing to do with it. You just need to accept that you're in a scientific discipline, where the rules of evidence and experiment apply.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting Out- and Inputstream multiple times.
Last time I worked with sockets you could get only one. Consecutive calls will return the same stream. And closing it will close the socket

You either need a protocol to identify when a new file starts and ends or open and close a new connection for each file.

Usually you have two channels, one open for the whole transaction, one opened per file.

Comment: Last time you worked with sockets you came to a completely erroneous conclusion.

Comment: Thank you @EJP for this constructive feedback. The last time I used them is actually several years ago, so things might have changed, but reading your own response it seems it is still true, that you cannot open and close multiple streams on a socket. My wording was not precise though, so I will enhance :-)

Comment: Nothing has changed. Calling getInputStream() or getOutputStream() multiple times on a Socket has always returned the same object, as you now agree, and therefore cannot possibly cause concerns with GC, as you stated in your original answer, which you have now altered, and which was never true. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

'Socket closed' means you closed the socket and then kept working with it.

Closing the input stream or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.